# Boolean indexing to retain falsy values as NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

Given a dataframe:

```
                         Data
1                      246804
2                      135272
3                      898.01
4                     3453.33
5                       shine  
6                        add
7                         522
8                         Nan
9                      string
10                      29.11
11                        20
```

I would like two new columns `Floats` and `Strings`, both having the same length as the original dataframe. Getting the `Floats` column is easy:

```
In [176]: pd.to_numeric(df.Data, errors='coerce')
Out[176]: 
1     246804.00
2     135272.00
3        898.01
4       3453.33
5           NaN
6           NaN
7        522.00
8           NaN
9           NaN
10        29.11
11        20.00
Name: Data, dtype: float64
```

As you can see, non Floats are coerced to `NaN`, which is exactly what I want.

To get strings, this is what I do:

```
In [177]: df[df.Data.str.isalpha()]
Out[177]: 
     Data
5   shine
6     add
8     Nan
9  string
```

But as you can see, it does not retain the non-String values as `NaN`. I want something like this:

```
1                       NaN
2                       NaN
3                       NaN
4                       NaN
5                       shine  
6                       add
7                       NaN
8                       Nan (not NaN)
9                       string
10                      NaN
11                      NaN
```

How can I get it to do so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get `Strings`, you can use Boolean Indexing on the `Data` column and located where `Floats` is null.

```
df['Floats'] = pd.to_numeric(df.Data, errors='coerce')
df['Strings'] = df.Data.loc[df.Floats.isnull()]  # Optional: .astype(str)

>>> df
# Output:
#        Data     Floats Strings
# 1    246804  246804.00     NaN
# 2    135272  135272.00     NaN
# 3    898.01     898.01     NaN
# 4   3453.33    3453.33     NaN
# 5     shine        NaN   shine
# 6       add        NaN     add
# 7       522     522.00     NaN
# 8       Nan        NaN     Nan
# 9    string        NaN  string
# 10    29.11      29.11     NaN
# 11       20      20.00     NaN
```

Comment: While the other answers were superb, I can appreciate the simplicity of this the most, honestly. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
floats = pd.to_numeric(df.Data, 'coerce')
pd.DataFrame(dict(
    floats=floats,
    strings=df.Data.mask(floats.notnull())
))

       floats strings
1   246804.00     NaN
2   135272.00     NaN
3      898.01     NaN
4     3453.33     NaN
5         NaN   shine
6         NaN     add
7      522.00     NaN
8         NaN     Nan
9         NaN  string
10      29.11     NaN
11      20.00     NaN
```

---

You can even make it more obvious within `mask` by passing an alternative

```
floats = pd.to_numeric(df.Data, 'coerce')
pd.DataFrame(dict(
    floats=floats,
    strings=df.Data.mask(floats.notnull(), '')
))

       floats strings
1   246804.00        
2   135272.00        
3      898.01        
4     3453.33        
5         NaN   shine
6         NaN     add
7      522.00        
8         NaN     Nan
9         NaN  string
10      29.11        
11      20.00
```

Comment: I liked this answer as well because it taught me something. I wish I could accept more than one, but I had to go with Alexander's answer because that seemed the simplest of them all. Nonetheless thank you for the answer :)

Comment: Don't make me go all editorial on this post.  I up-voted his answer half a second after he posted it.  I care far more about up-votes than I do about accepted answers.  I think out of the box and my answer typically look different from everyone else's.  I expect that often times another's answer will be more palatable.  I only ever get disgruntled when I see an OP not select an answer at all among very good answers.  Also, don't feel that you have to explain or justify your choice.  His is a very good answer and I'm an adult, I can totally handle it.  Well... maybe not an adult, but w/e.

Comment: @piRSquared Thank you... I can respect that. I'll have a lot of questions in the future... please continue to grace us all with your expertise!

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
df.Data.where(pd.to_numeric(df.Data, errors='coerce').isnull())
Out[186]: 
      Data
1      NaN
2      NaN
3      NaN
4      NaN
5    shine
6      add
7      NaN
8      Nan #not NaN
9   string
10     NaN
11     NaN
```

Or base on your `df.Data.str.isalpha()`

```
df['Data'].where(df['Data'].str.isalpha())
```

Comment: I like you answer!

Comment: Brb, undoing some downvotes to up vote your answer too xD

Comment: That made me laugh

Comment: @piRSquared LOL :)

Comment: Nitpick: with this is that you modify the original column.

Comment: In addition, this answer overwrites the original values in `Data`, so the numeric data is lost.

Comment: `df['Data'].where(df['Data'].str.isalpha())` if you don't want to modify the data column - it returns a copy.

Comment: @Alexander, thank you !!!! that is help me know it better , That is why I love SO